# Computing $A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha+k\beta)^{k-1}e^{-(\alpha+k\beta)}}{k!}f^{k}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, closed-form, order-statistics

I'm working on a problem in order statistics. I am hoping to obtain a closed form solution for the following infinite sum:

$$A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha+k\beta)^{k-1}e^{-(\alpha+k\beta)}}{k!}f^{k}$$

where $$\alpha=1$$ and $$\beta=0.5.$$

This is the probability generating function for a so-called Generalized Poisson distribution. I have plugged the equation into Mathematica, but it simply returns back the sum. I would like to work out this specific case first, and then proceed to the more general case.

Please note that this particular case *must* converge. For example, if we compute this for a large maximum value of $k$ say $100$, you get a sensible numerical answer (which is between $0$ and $1$ as this is a probability if $f$ is between $0$ and $1$).

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be expressed in terms of the [Lambert $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Let $\color{blue}{L(z)=-W_0(-z)/z}$ for $|z|<1/e$; then, for any complex $\lambda$, we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Integer_and_complex_powers) $$L(z)^\lambda=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lambda(n+\lambda)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n!},$$ so that $\color{blue}{A=e^{-\alpha}L(\beta e^{-\beta}f)^{\alpha/\beta}}$ under obvious conditions.

A possible proof of the above is to deal with $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ (and then extend to the general case by the observation that the coefficients of both power series are polynomials in $\lambda$) using [Lagrange–Bürmann formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Lagrange%E2%80%93B%C3%BCrmann_formula) which states that, given analytic functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ with $\phi(0)\neq 0$, if we let $f(w)=w/\phi(w)$ then, using the "coefficient-of" notation, $$[z^n]\psi\big(f^{-1}(z)\big)=\frac1n[w^{n-1}]\big(\psi'(w)\phi(w)^n\big).$$ We apply this to $\phi(w)=e^w$ and $\psi(w)=w^\lambda$. Then $f^{-1}(z)=zL(z)$ and, for $n\geqslant\lambda$, $$[z^n]\big(zL(z)\big)^\lambda=\frac1n[w^{n-1}]\big(\lambda w^{\lambda-1}e^{nw}\big)=\frac{\lambda n^{n-\lambda-1}}{(n-\lambda)!}.$$ This is equivalent to $[z^n]L(z)^\lambda=\lambda(n+\lambda)^{n-1}/n!$, exactly as needed.

Other ideas can be seen in *Concrete mathematics* [Graham & *Knuth* & Patashnik] ($2$nd edition, section $5.4$ etc) and *The Art of Computer Programming* vol. $2$ ($3$rd edition, exercise $4.7.22$).

Comment: much appreciated. a proof of the above would be very helpful indeed.

Comment: please note that lambert function has no beta factor on the n in the brackets of the infinite sum. the beta value, for this specific case, should be less than 1 but positive.

Comment: This is indeed correct having just checked this.

Comment: @user1016210: Added a proof.

Comment: Another very interesting related question is: Again, let $$\alpha>0$$ and $$1>\beta>0$$ what would the closed form solution for: $$B=\sum_{k=i}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha+k\beta)^{k-1}e^{-(\alpha+k\beta)}}{(k-i)!}f{}^{k}$$ be?

Comment: I posted the above also as a separate question. I have attempted to use the W lambert function but it doesn't quite fit so far.